# How to show history of pop up/dialogue boxes

Tags: macbook-pro, adobe, dialog

Is it possible to show the history of pop up/dialogue boxes? I clicked on one but didn’t remember a crucial piece of information.

(In particular, I used Migration Assistant to copy my programs from my old MacBook Pro from 2010 to my new 2021 model. This included Lightroom 6. When I clicked on it to open it, there was a box that came up that is the one I want to see again. It said something like that it needed me to install another program to make it compatible. I did so. And then there kept being other boxes popping up saying that these Cisco files were a security threat. I deleted them and now Lightroom won’t open. It flashes for a brief second but doesn’t load.)

Comment: It looks like it works in some cases. https://community.adobe.com/t5/lightroom-classic-discussions/is-lightroom-6-compatible-with-mac-os-monterey/td-p/12490971

Comment: Then reinstall it it you think it's going to work completely and properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately the system does not keep any history of pop-ups, dialog boxes or modals.

You could try removing Lightroom 6 and either copying it from the old computer again or installing it from scratch. Perhaps that will trigger the same dialog box.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Unfortunately the downloader from scratch doesn't work. I don't know how to copy it over...

Comment: You could use a USB pen drive or similar and copy it using the Finder.